# SUSE 15 SP3 - After modifying ens33 external interface name to eth0 SSH is not working with sshd service restart

Tags: ssh, network-interface, sshd, suse, sles

OS - SLES
Version - 15-SP3

I am successfully updating the external network interface name from ens33 to eth0. On reboot, the ifconfig is giving output with eth0 as a device and SSH is also turned on.

I need to turn on the SSH without a reboot after performing the same changes(external network interface name change from ens33 to eth0).

Can someone please help me to know how can I do that ?

Comment: Note that it is explicitly discouraged to rename network interfaces to `eth`+digit on systemd based systems, see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16665 .

Comment: This is a specific need for the existing workflow hence the need to rename the network card. BTW, thanks for the info.